# How can I produce the reflection of a pstricks image in pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, reflection

I defined some small pstricks makro:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \newcommand{\leftwall}{%
    \psline(-4,-4)(-4,4)
    \multips(-4,-3.5)(0,0.5){14}{\psline(0,0)(-1,1)}
    }
    \leftwall
\end{pspicture}
```

And now I want the output of `\leftwall` reflected, to produce something like `\rightwall`. In this specific situation, I could just change the signs of the x coordinates, but this is ugly. How can I do this in general?
I'm looking for a command like `\psrotate` from the pstricks-add package where I can specify two points that define a line along which I can reflect my `\leftwall`.

Comment: Please show me the minimal code and use CODE tag please :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extend the example in a case that `\leftwall` and `\rightwall` allow coordinates to get rid of the `\rput`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newcommand\leftwall{%  
  \psline(-4,-4)(-4,4) 
  \psframe[linestyle=none,fillstyle=vlines](-4,-4)(-4.75,4)}
\newcommand\rightwall{\psscalebox{-1 1}{\leftwall}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5) 
 \leftwall \rput(0,0){\rightwall}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the core of your answer (apart from other improvements to the code) is:

Use \psscalebox{-1 1}{stuff}.

Together with rotations, reflections on arbitrary lines can be made.